# Lambda expression to get list of members from list of objects?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I am using VS 2008.

I have a little user control that has a method whose argument is of type `List<String>`. I have a list of objects (call it `MyObjectList`, of type `List<MyObject>`) whose definition includes one String member (call it `myString`).

I want to get a `List<String>` that contains all of the `myString` strings from `MyObjectList`.

Of course, I can write a little loop that walks through `MyObjectList`, adding every `myString` value to a `List<String>` object. But I am trying to be as modern as I can.

With the advent of lambda expressions, I think there must be a better way to do this. Is there? If so, how? And is the answer any different in VS 2012?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your list is a `List<MyObject>` and that class `MyObject` has a property `MyString`, you could use LINQ and a lambda to do this:

```
var listOfStrings = myObjectList.Select(o => o.MyString).ToList();
```

This will work in any assembly that targets .NET 3.0 or greater; the version of VS doesn't matter.